# Integrating Python or Perl with PHP

Tags: php, python, perl, integration, phpbb

I'm going to help my friend in a improve of his phpBB board, but I want to make somethings there in Python or Perl. But it's possible to integrate these languages with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Perl PECL package](http://pecl.php.net/package/perl) to integrate Perl into PHP.

Answer (score 8):

You can always call the python or perl interpreter from within PHP! Minimalistic interchange is possible by means of passing command line arguments and capturing stdout (`exec` or `passthru` are related php functions).

However, I don't think its's a good idea - using two interpreters instead of one doubles the overall runtime overhead and startup time.

Comment: It doesn't double startup time, it'll increase it a hundredfold.  Not starting interpreters for each request is the reason FastCGI/SCGI exist.  You'll be killing that, reverting to the old CGI method of starting processes constantly.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that the only reasonable way of doing that is if you are making a separate service, that you talk to via Ajax or XML or something like that. Everything else is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: This also helps later on if you start scaling across multiple boxes

Comment: Pretty much any RPC mechanism will work, as long as it has good support in P(erl|ython) and PHP.